# WSO2 - currently called api on gatewa and integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

is it possible somewhere in wso2 gw and integrator to watch the number of current calls?
I found nothing in the wso2 documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you need to watch the number of service calls served by EI (WSO2 Integrator ESB-Profile) during that moment, there is no out of the box approach available. But if you need statistics about number of service calls served (and many more statistics) in a given time range, you can use EI-Analytics [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+Analytics

Thanks,
Milinda